# React-Navigation useIsFocused always returns true, and I can't figure out why?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

I have pretty simple use case for this, Basically if the screen is focused I want this function to run, if not don't run.

```
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const onViewRef = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => {

    if (!isFocused) return;

    //code to run
  });
```

Here's the stack for this screen in particular:

```
const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen
        component={MyStackComponent}
        name="My"
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

And here is that stack being use in a tabNavigator

```
     <Tab.Screen
        component={MyStack}
        name="My"
      />
      <Tab.Screen
          component={Other Stack}
          name="Other"
        />
```

So basically whenever I go to any other tab on my app, the file using the useIsFocused hook should should return false right? Because right now it returns true no matter what, and I can't have that function running all the time. Any pointers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to bring a real answer to this topic.

For some reason, in my case too, `useIsFocused()` always `return true;` from the moment I arrive on the screen in question for the first time untill I kill the app (IOS).

So I found another solution: use the `navigation.isFocused()` method from react-navigation. (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#isfocused)

And it works perfectly !
Hoping it will help someone

Here is my example:

```
useEffect(() => {
        notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
            if (navigation.isFocused()) {
                fetchConversationsList();
            }
        });
    }, [fetchConversationsList, navigation]);
```

Answer (score -1):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation

```
tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size })
```

Comment: You might want to [edit] the post to contain more information than a line of code + a link. Please mention why this would help, e.g. by summarising the contents behind the link in one or two sentences